How to plot a piecewise pdf with one variable. The graph is not visible
 Clear[\[Theta], \[Alpha], \[Lambda]];

 c = 1/(Integrate[\[Lambda] Exp[-\[Lambda] y], {y, 0, \[Theta]}] + 
 Integrate[\[Alpha] \[Theta]^\[Alpha] y^(-1 - \[Alpha]), {y, \
 \[Theta], Infinity}]);

 f1[y_] := 
 c (\[Lambda]* Exp[-\[Lambda] *y])/(1 - Exp[-\[Lambda] *\[Theta]]);

 f2[y_] := (1 - c) \[Alpha] *\[Theta]^\[Alpha]* y^(-1 - \[Alpha]);

 Integrate[f1[y], {y, 0, \[Theta]}] + 
 Integrate[ f2[y], {y, \[Theta], Infinity}];

The above integral indicates that the piecewise function defined below is a pdf, however, I cannot get its graph.
 Plot[Piecewise[{{ f1[y], {y, 0, \[Theta]}}}, {  
 f2[y], {y, \[Theta], 20}}], {y, 0, 20}]

 \[Theta] = 5; \[Lambda] = 2; \[Alpha] = \[Lambda] \[Theta]Exp[-\[Lambda] \[Theta]];

 g1 = Plot[f1[y], {y, 0, \[Theta]}]
  g2 = Plot[f2[y], {y, \[Theta], 20}]
 
  Also, The command show does not combine the individual graphs. Thankyou

  Show[{g1, g2}]


If you look at what your f1[y] generates you see number of parameters which has no numerical values such as  lambda and theta and alpha . Plot can't plot expression with parameters in them that have no numerical values. One easy way to find why plot shows nothing is to evaluate the thing you are trying to plot on some random values of its range variable, then you will quickly see the problem.

As per @Nasser's comment, put the definitions of theta, lambda, and alpha beforeyou define the functions. Otherwise, they won't show up in the definitions of those functions. Other than that, look up Piecewise in the documentation for the proper syntax of that function.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear[θ, α, λ];

c = Assuming[α > 0 && θ > 0,
  1/(Integrate[λ Exp[-λ y], {y, 0, θ}] + 
     Integrate[α θ^α y^(-1 - α), {y, θ, Infinity}])]

(* 1/(2 - E^(-θ λ)) *)

f1[y_] := 
  c (λ*Exp[-λ*y])/(1 - Exp[-λ*θ]);

f2[y_] := (1 - c) α*θ^α*y^(-1 - α);

Assuming[α > 0 && θ > 0,
 Integrate[f1[y], {y, 0, θ}] + 
   Integrate[f2[y], {y, θ, Infinity}] // Simplify]

(* 1 *)

θ = 5; λ = 2; α = λ θ Exp[-λ θ];

Plot[
 Piecewise[{{f1[y], 0 <= y < θ}, {f2[y], θ <= y <= 20}}],
 {y, 0, 20},
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.4},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]


Show[
 Plot[f1[y], {y, 0, θ}],
 Plot[f2[y], {y, θ, 20}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.4}},
 Frame -> True]


